# Open with explorer working/not working?

Tags: document-library, open-with-explorer

my open to explorer option works for some libraries and for some it doesn't under different subsite, do i need to enable something in site settings? I am using sharepoint 2013

Comment: I don't think you did the StackOverflow-101 *10 minutes search before asking a question* step https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=open+explorer

Comment: I Did but couldn't found any satisfactory answers. Moreover this functionality is working in IE for some libraries. I Am confused about that. So read my question carefully again.

Comment: Hmm.. 15+ years of Open with Explorer and 800+ SO Questions..

Comment: Still unable to answer this simple question??